# Al crear una colección en Laravel la propiedad $items contiene un array de mis elementos

Tags: laravel, colecciones

Antes que nada una disculpa por el titulo todo raro, la verdad no sabia como expresarlo. Tengo el siguiente problema desde hace ya unos días y aunque puedo trabajar con esto sigo con la espinita de saber como arreglarlo. Verán, tengo una colección de datos similar a esta:

```
[
    0 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
        ...
    ],
    1 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
        ...
    ],
    2 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
        ...
    ]
    ...
];
```

Y al convertirla en una colección (`collect($datos)`) me queda de la siguiente manera:

```
array:x [▼
  "xxxxxxx" => Collection {#520 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx"
      ]
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Como pueden ver en la colección generada esta la propiedad `items` que es en donde se guardan los valores de la colección. El problema es que en este caso de esta guardando un array dentro del array `items` y me dificulta utilizar algunas propiedades de las colecciones, por ejemplo cuando uso `$datos->get("dato1")` no me da nada, pero si uso `$datos->get(0)["dato1"]` si que me da valor. En otras palabras lo que quiero es que en vez de quedar así:

```
array:x [▼
  "xxxxxxx" => Collection {#520 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx"
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx"
      ]
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Quede así:

```
array:x [▼
  "xxxxxxx" => Collection {#520 ▼
    #items: array:4 [▼
      "dato1" => "xxxxxxx"
      "dato2" => "xxxxxxx"
      "dato3" => "xxxxxxx"
      "dato4" => "xxxxxxx"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Como mencione no es un problema súper grave que no me deje trabajar, pero igual me gustaría saber por que pasa y si alguien sabe como evitar este tipo de situaciones.

Saludos!

Comment: probaste con `collect($datos[0])` o  `collect(array_values($datos))` ?

Comment: `collect($datos[0])` solo me hace la colección del primer elemento de mi array `datos` y `collect(array_values($datos))` hace exactamente lo mismo que solo poner `collect($datos)` :(

Comment: entonces, para saber si estoy entendiendo bien. ¿lo que quieres es que cada item de la colección también sea una colección y no un array? o ¿quieres que todos los los pares clave/valor de los arrays pasen a un mismo nivel en la colección? lo que pones en la pregunta `$datos->get("dato1")` no sería posible, pues en cada subarray tiene una clave 'dato1'

Comment: No, justo como esta ahora esta perfecto, solo que cada elemento de la colección es un array tal cual ` 0 => array:4 [▼` dentro de `#items` y lo que me gustaría es que no fuera un array, sino que se estos sean parte de `#items: array:1 [▼`

Comment: Edite la pregunta para poner el como que gustaría que quede

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que los arrays internos sean una colección, puedes probar de la siguiente manera usando map():

```
$mi_coleccion = collect($array)
                    ->map(function($subarray) {
                        return collect($subarray);
                    });
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `$array` es el array que muestras en la pregunta:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
    ],
    1 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
    ],
    2 => [
        "dato1" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato2" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato3" => "xxxxxxx",
        "dato4" => "xxxxxxx",
    ]
];
```